# Buttons do not show up when specifying location property in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying dynamically add panels within a panel dependent on the count of people in a list using the following code when the form loads:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int xConst = 2;
    var people = new List<string>
    {
        "Person1",
        "Person2",
        "Person3",
        "Person4",
    };
    var y = 2;
    for (var x = 0; x < people.Count; x++)
    {
        var newpan = new MyPanel
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            Height = 25,
            Width = panel1.Width - 5,
            Location = new Point(xConst, y)
        };
        var newlbl = new Label
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            AutoSize = false,
            Text = people[x],
            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.5F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
            Size = new Size(75,20),
            Location = new Point(newpan.Location.X + 2, newpan.Location.Y + 2),
        };
        var newbtn = new Button
        {
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
            FlatAppearance = { BorderSize = 0 },
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
            Text = @"+",
            Size = new Size(15,21),
            Location = new Point(newpan.Width - 20,newpan.Location.Y - 1),
            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)))
        };
        newpan.Controls.Add(newlbl);
        newpan.Controls.Add(newbtn);
        panel1.Controls.Add(newpan);
        y += 27;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I specify the Location property in both the button and the label, only the first iteration of the labels and buttons show up for the `Person1` iteration.  But, if I leave the Location property out, they all show up.  The problem with that is that I have a custom panel that overrides some stuff allowing me to put a customer border and color around the panels, and if I don't specify a location, the labels and buttons aren't positioned correctly on the panel, so it covers my border and looks sloppy.

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?  I've stepped through the program completely and watched all the values I can think of increment accordingly in the watch window.  All the panels show up correctly, so I don't understand why their respective labels and buttons don't show up when I specify the location.

Comment: You are using your panels location property to assign the y position to your controls. This property is based on your panel1 position. Therefore your first component's y coordinate will be 4, the next iteration will be 29, the next will be 56, etc. This will eventually move your components out of view. You want to use coordinates based on your newpan panel, most likely 0.

Comment: Maybe you should look into using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of trying to position things manually.  Also, don;t manually add multiple controls to multiple `Panel`s.  Design a user control and then just add multiple instances of that to the form.

Comment: @MarkHall I don't understand....  You recommend basing my button and label Locations off of my newpan panel, but that is exactly what I'm doing...  ie. `new Point(newpan.Location.X + 2,newpan.Location.Y + 2)`

Comment: You are basing it off the location of the newpan panel which is based on your panel location and is constantly changing. I would do away with it and use a fixed offset or one set by your border width

Comment: That still makes no sense.... I must be missing or not understanding something, but I'll reiterate that my panels all show up perfectly, and I am indeed basing my button and label locations based off each new panel, and the first label and button show up just fine.  Looking at the values, the buttons and labels should be appearing in the correct place.  So, outside of that, I'd need to see an alternate working example to see what's wrong.

Comment: are you wanting your y coordinates incrementing by 29 pixels? Because that is what you are doing. I am not talking about your panel location but your component location, the height of your newpanel is 25 your components y coordinates will be at 29 on the second iteration, out of view.

Comment: I use the y += 27 for the panels since they're 25 in height, and I want them separated by a small amount to make sure borders don't overlap, which works perfectly fine for the panels, and I just want the labels and buttons for each panel to show up in the correct spot within each panel.

Comment: you are also incrementing newpan.Location by 27

Comment: I'll also add, that I just tested commenting out the panel part, and just adding Labels to the main panel, and they all show up in order just fine...

Comment: it would, your panel is larger than your newpan, try removing the newpan.Location from your location statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90273/discussion-between-tekgiant-and-mark-hall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I notice that you are setting your newpan height to 25, and its position is offset by 27 with each iteration. You also are using

```
 'Location = new Point(newpan.Location.X + 2, newpan.Location.Y + 2)
```

to set the location of your button and label within your newpan panel. newpan.Location is referenced in the coordinates of your panel1, your button and label's location is referenced in the coordinates of your newpan panel therefore after the first iteration of your For statement your label and buttons y location value is 29 which is greater than the height of your newpan panel making it not able to be seen, the next iteration after that will be y will be 56 and so forth. Each content control, in this case your panels will have its own coordinate system, the easiest fix would be to do something like this:

```
'Location = new Point( 2, 2) //for your label
'Location = new Point(newpan.Width - 20, - 1) //for your button
```

The other alternative is to do like jmcilhinney suggests and make an UserControl with your button and label already in position, you would then create individual instances of it and assign it to your panel1.

Comment: I would need to see an example of @jmcilhinney 's solution.  I wouldn't know how to implement that most likely.